# Android: best way to handle versions of Google dependencies in a library project

Tags: android, gradle, versions

I maintain an Android open source library, via GitHub and jCenter. That library uses parts of Google play services and Android's support libraries.

Android Studio gives a warning when you don't reference a specific version of those libs in build.gradle. However, when we do, we constantly have to "chase" Google's releases, or our uses have version mismatch.

What is a good way to handle this?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This is a good question for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this issue all the time with large projects that use many 3rd party dependencies. What I tend to do is exclude some of the transitive dependencies from the 3rd party libs and make sure to include my own. This does require that you review the `androidDependencies` in your app and make sure that you are finding where the transitive dependencies are coming from.

Here is a link to the gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies

Here is a simple example of what I have done in one of my projects:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```